# (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (127.0.0.1,4096)\n')

Tags: python, sql-server, pymysql, pymssql

I tried connecting to a SQL Server database and the following errors occurred.

> (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:
> Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (127.0.0.1,4096)

Checks I made:

1. TTP/IP enabled for port 4096
2. Tried both named pipes enabled and disabled
3. Security>login>AA Server roles dbcreator.
4. Enabled Remote connection

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(
host=r'127.0.0.1,4096',
user=r'AA',
password=r'BBBBBBBBBBBB',
database='table'
)
cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
print(row\[0\])
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: Are you *sure* your SQL Server is running on port 4096? That isn't the default port.

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1:4096 perhaps?

Comment: Seems like something that might be covered in the [pymssql FAQ](https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html), as in: _Note that pymssql will use a default port of 1433, despite any ports you may have specified in your `freetds.conf` file. So if you have SQL Server running on a port other than 1433, you must explicitly specify the `port` in your call to `pymssql.connect`. You cannot rely on it to pick up the port in your `freetds.conf`, even though `tsql -S` might do this. This is why I recommend using `tsql -H` instead for diagnosing connection problems._

Comment: See also the examples at the above link, showing that there is a separate `port` named parameter to `pymssql.connect()`.

Comment: @siggemannen  no its not working either.

Comment: @Larnu yes its not the default port, i set the dynamic port to 4096.

Comment: Did you open firewall for that port? And also, according to this, you're supposed to pass a dedicated param as @AlwaysLearning wrote: https://www.pymssql.org/ref/pymssql.html